# Javascript Syntax error in IE explorer 11, but ok in Chrome

Tags: javascript

I have a small bit of code that works fine in chrome with no errors. When run in Internet explorer I get a syntax error, but i'm not familiar enough with the differences to know what is causing the error.

```
    sleep(1000).then(() => {
            resetTDcolor(SRID)
            });
```

The error is indicated on the first line of the above code.  The sleep function and reset function are below in case they help.

```
   function sleep (time) {
       return new Promise((resolve) => setTimeout(resolve, time));
   }

   function resetTDcolor(SRID){
       var SR = document.getElementsByClassName('scoutRequirement' + SRID);
       for (i=0;i<SR.length;i++){
         SR[i].style.backgroundColor = '';
       }
   }
```

Any help or clarification would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Internet explorer doesn't really support [ES6 arrow](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions) functions, you would have to rewrite it as `function(resolve) { setTimeout(resolve, time); }`. I'm not even sure if Internet explorer has a basic support for Promise

Comment: have a look here https://kangax.github.io/compat-table/es6/ 
IE 11 doesn't support arrow functions
Either rewrite it or use babel f.e.

Comment: or you could use babel.

Comment: @icepickle I changed the code  and that particular line is no longer coming up as a syntax error.  Unfortunately there are still way too many errors on the page to make sure it functions in IE correctly. (it does in Chrome.) so for now, I'll take this as win.

Comment: The solution I implemented was as follows

 1. goto:  https://babeljs.io/repl
    
 2.   Paste in your code and select es2015.

 3.  In your new code paste the following, if you are using **forEach** (which is again not supported in IE) :

    if (window.NodeList && !NodeList.prototype.forEach) {
        NodeList.prototype.forEach = Array.prototype.forEach;
    }

 
 4. Use **indexOf** instead of **includes**

Answer (score 7):

Internet Explorer 11 has no [Promise](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise#Browser_compatibility), as well as no [arrow function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions#Browser_compatibility).